# Android device: How to connect wifi by "Adb shell cmd wifi" command?

Tags: android, automation, adb, android-wifi, appium-android

Android device:  How to connect wifi by "Adb shell cmd wifi" command?

I tried to connect wifi by adb to avoid tedious click and verification operations by appium. And i found that the "adb shell cmd wifi" have a keyword "connect-network", but i cant connect the wifi by this way. Does anyone know how to use it? Thank a lot guys!

**Here is the usage of the "Adb shell cmd wifi connect-network":Wi-Fi (wifi) commands:**

```
  connect-network <ssid> open|owe|wpa2|wpa3 [<passphrase>] [-m] [-d] [-b <bssid>]
    Connect to a network with provided params and add to saved networks list
    <ssid> - SSID of the network
    open|owe|wpa2|wpa3 - Security type of the network.
        - Use 'open' or 'owe' for networks with no passphrase
           - 'open' - Open networks (Most prevalent)
           - 'owe' - Enhanced open networks
        - Use 'wpa2' or 'wpa3' for networks with passphrase
           - 'wpa2' - WPA-2 PSK networks (Most prevalent)
           - 'wpa3' - WPA-3 PSK networks
    -m - Mark the network metered.
    -d - Mark the network autojoin disabled.
    -b <bssid> - Set specific BSSID.
```

And my input is `adb shell cmd wifi connect-network WIFIName open wpa2 Loginpassword`, it return me a `Connection initiated`, But the connect is not successful. Why this happen? Should i input the wifi login account? And what the whole command should be?

Answer (score 0):

Hey I think that you should use either 'open' or 'wpa2' not both. But If we assume that wifi is secured by a wpa2 password so proper command would be:

```
adb shell cmd wifi connect-network WIFIName wpa2 password
```

Also, take into consideration that only the root user can invoke wifi commands, and root access is not available in most cases.

Comment: Got you, but i cant get the root access. I think i need to keep simulating some click operation to connect wifi by Appium. Thanks for your answer!